# Ubuntu 18.04 speaker cracks even if muted

Tags: xubuntu

My old speaker cracks on xubuntu 18.04. Booting windows from usb the speaker are working. The pc has a asus p8p67 motherboard.

The loudspeaker cracks even if no sound is played, it looks as if the loudspeaker is plugged in new each time and the volume bar pops up every time on the right top.

```
lspci -v 
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. GF114 HDMI Audio Controller
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not, have intel chipset.

Comment: Hi Crankle, can you [try running Ubuntu from a Live USB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0) (or Windows, even) and confirm you are still having the same problem? If so, then it almost certainly is a hardware issue and nothing we can solve at the OS level here at Ask Ubuntu, sorry.

Comment: Okay, it's a software problem. I've booted windows from usb and the speaker are working.

Comment: Hi Crankle, how about another version of Ubuntu from Live USB? Do you still get the problem then?

Comment: Hi, I've tried lubuntu 18.04.3 there the speakers works without problems. I've compared the alsamixer settings, they are the same. But I've noticed that the volume is much louder by lubuntu at the same volume setting. I've also tried xubuntu 18.04.2 and there it is also much better, I don't have the volume pops (the pop up normally appears if I change the volume).

Comment: So, can we conclude that the problem you are having is specific to a distro version? And that is `Xubuntu 18.04.3`? If so, this sounds like a bug that should be reported.

Comment: Also, when you say "tried xubuntu 18.04.2 and there it is also much better", do you mean the problem is gone, or it's not as bad? I'm trying to help get the problem as specific as possible.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info's. The distro with the problems is a xubuntu 18.04.3 with a Kernel 5.0.0-25-generic. Xubuntu 18.04.2 from the live CD works better, the pop-up messages were gone, but sometimes there was a crackle, but not as loud and not as often as on the 18.04.03.